# How can I use COUNTIF and TODAY functions to identify work deadlines in multiple worksheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been playing with our spreadsheets at work and have been able to create a basic formula that will identify when there is a deadline on today's date that needs completing. The issue I now have stems from people wanting to identify when they have completed the deadlines.

The formula I've created works great for single instances, but isn't clever enough to pick up when there are multiple deadlines - when one deadline is completed, it shows all deadlines as complete.

I want to avoid referencing every single cell where possible, however if there's a way to make the formula identify that if the cell one to the left of the one containing today's date is still blank, that the work is to be completed. When today's date is inputted into that cell, the work is complete.

The example of the formula is:

`=(IF(COUNTIF('S5'!P:Q,"="&TODAY()),"Action","No Action")&IF(COUNTIF('S5'!O:O,"="&TODAY())," Completed",""))`

`S5` is the name of the workbook tab, `Column O` is referenced and it would be this column where today's date is put when completed.

Effectively it needs to say that if it's saying today's date in `Column P` or `Q` and `Column O` is blank that it still shows the word Action, even if other work on that day has been completed.

Comment: According to what you describe, this formula works for TODAY. If the date is not today's date, it will not. I entered today's date in `P` and `Q` which resulted in the word "Action". If I enter yesterday's date, is shows "No Action". Is that the intended result? Should it be `<=TODAY`?

Comment: I'm not sure the formula you've given is even remotely close to what you're trying to achieve. Are you wanting to have one cell show Action/No Action/Completed for the entire sheet, or put a status cell on each row?

Comment: It's to show just what needs to be done Today so anything due on the day before or is late is irrelevant for this purpose. It's a sort of one off collective status for each stage of the process we do.

Comment: This is clearly a calendaring type issue so why are you not using calendaring/scheduling software?  For example:  Google Calendar.  You can have multiple shared calendars and you can easily click on any date and/or time and type "Deadline for Project X" and save. Another user can add "completed" when done.  Each person can have a personal calendar and shared calendars for group work and/or global company overview.  Its web bases and can be synced with people cell phones as a bonus.  Either that or use proper project management software like this:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/projectlibre/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(COUNTIF(P:Q,TODAY()),"Action","No Action"),IF(COUNTIF(O:O,TODAY())=COUNTIF(P:Q,TODAY())," Completed",""))
```

Some stylistic notes:

- I generally prefer the `CONCATENATE` function instead of smashing output strings together with ampersand. However, the formula should work with either.
- For references to cells in the same worksheet, it is not required to define the worksheet name. If you're putting the formula in a sheet other than 'SS', you'll need to add in the sheet reference.

What the formula does:

1. Instead of using ampersands, the `CONCATENATE` function is used to assemble the output of the inner formulas.
2. The first part of the formula output is defined according to the results of an `IF` function.
3. `COUNTIF` is used to tally the number of cells in columns P & Q which match today's date.
4. If `COUNTIF` returns zero, `IF` will treat the response as FALSE. Any other value is treated as TRUE.

   - Note: If the cells are not formatted as dates, or time elements are added, incorrect results may be returned.
5. If the first `IF` statement evaluates to TRUE, the first part of the output string will be "Action". Otherwise, the first part of the output string will be "No Action".
6. The second part of the formula output is defined according to the results of another `IF` function.
7. `COUNTIF` is used twice here - first to check how many items in column O match today's date, then to check again how many items in columns P & Q match today's date. The two `COUNTIF`s are then compared, to provide the TRUE/FALSE status for the `IF` function.
8. IF the results of the `COUNTIF`s match exactly, `IF` will evaluate to TRUE - otherwise, FALSE.

   - Note: If the cells are not formatted as dates, or time elements are added, incorrect results may be returned.
9. When the IF statement evaluates to TRUE, the second part of the output string will be " Completed". Otherwise, it will be blank.

It is worth noting that there is still some fallacy to this method. Particularly, if work is logged as completed today but was not due today (work completed ahead of or behind schedule), then today's result may show " Completed" even though there is other work still due today. Similarly, if all work that was due today or earlier was completed today or earlier *and* some work which was due tomorrow was also completed, the output will never show " Completed" tomorrow unless an equal amount of work is completed ahead of time tomorrow. Also, there is no logic in here at all to account for overdue items still outstanding.

Some case examples of the fallacy:

- 10 projects are due today. 8 of today's projects were completed today. The other 2 projects due today are not completed. 1 project overdue from yesterday was completed today. 1 project that was due tomorrow was completed ahead of time today. The output of the formula will be "Action Completed" even though 2 projects due today are still not completed.
- 10 projects are due today. 3 of those projects were completed yesterday. The other 7 projects were completed today. No other work was completed today. Even though all of today's projects are complete, the output will still not say " Completed".
- 10 projects are due today, and were completed today. No other work was completed today. However, there are 5 projects still not completed which were due before today. The status will show "Action Completed" even though there is still work to be done.

Without knowing more precisely what columns P & Q represent, or being more familiar with your requirements, it would be a bit difficult to come up with a formula that more properly reflects an accurate status. However, such formula would probably involve the use of at least one additional column (to separately track work completed for each deadline, and/or individually evaluate the status of each line item) and some use of `COUNTIFS`.